# Fortran format, what does the symbol "1" mean?

Tags: fortran

Please consider this statement:

```
           *
format(2i4,1 12(f4.1,1x,a2,1x,a5))
```

Is my understanding that this line reads : 2 integers of 4 digits and 12 groups of:

```
- a 4 digits float with one decimal
- one format space
- an alphabetic string of two chars
- one format space
- an alphabetic string of five chars
```

But I don't understand the one in the middle (marked with a star on top of it), can someone please explain what it means?

The given expression is supposed to parse:

```
59 229 7.2 Ms HRV   7.3 Mw P&S   7.3 Ms P&S   7.1 Ms ISC   7.2 Ms PAS   7.4 Ms BRK   6.3 mb ISC   6.2 mb NEIS
```

thanks

Comment: can that be 112?   space is insignificant in fortran

Comment: @yosukesabai don't think so. however, i know zero about fortran. I've added a string that should be parseable by the expression if you would like to take a look at it.

Comment: as an aside you don't even need that format, a list directed read will work (*assuming* there are no spaces within the strings -- which appears to be the case )

Comment: It would be helpful to see the READ statement that uses this format.

Comment: @george the problem is that i am reading it with java. A third party supplied the list in the hopes that Fortran was used to read it, but that's not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found it: the symbol "1", quotes not part of the said symbol, means new line. Its just an odd, and if you ask me, antinatural, way to say \n.

thanks to everybody for helping.

Comment: Not exactly.  "1" when written to the output in column 1 means form feed.  That's not what is happening here.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler recognizes "1 12", which is probably a typo, as "112". The compiler ignores the space and doesn't notice the error because the format statement is syntactically correct.

The sample input that you provided would be parsed correctly with "8" in place of the "1 12".  "12" would work as well, and I'm guessing that's what the author intended.

If your corresponding "read" statement is only asking for 26 items, it'll work OK with 112 anyhow because it stops parsing when it has gotten all the items you asked for.